# Return From Async Function After Download and File Save are Complete in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, createwritestream

I have a sequence of events that go something like this:

```
//Download a file and write it to disk
await downloadSyncFile(user, downloadURL)
//Use the file...
await useTheFile() //Crash! The file is only partially there! Dangit!
```

My code keeps moving on before the file is actually on disk. Here's my download function:

```
async function downloadSyncFile(user, downloadURL){
  //Setup download path
  let path = './data/'+user+'/file.whatevs'

  try{
    //Download and save file
    let stream = fs.createWriteStream(path)
    let response = await axios.get(downloadURL, { responseType: 'stream' })
    response.data.pipe(stream)

    await new Promise(fulfill => stream.on('finish', fulfill))


  }catch(error){
    console.log('downloadSyncFile Error: '+error)
    return { success: false, message: error }
  }
}
```

Tthe `downloadSyncFile()` function seems to be returning after the `axios` download finishes, but the write to disk isn't done.

How can I make sure the file is safely written to disk before `downloadSyncFile()` returns?

Comment: You're swallowing the errors here—are you sure your `downloadSyncFile` is not returning an `{success:false,message:...}` object (return value of your catch statement)? Have you verified (eg with another event handler) that the `finish` event fires before the promise resolves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return the Promise from `downloadSyncFile()`.

Change

```
await new Promise(fulfill => stream.on('finish', fulfill));
```

to

```
return new Promise(fulfill => stream.on('finish', fulfill));
```

It would be better written like this:

```
async function downloadSyncFile(user, downloadURL) {
    return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
        let path = './data/' + user + '/file.whatevs';
        let stream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        let response = await axios.get(downloadURL, { responseType: 'stream' });
        response.data.pipe(stream);
        stream.on('finish', fulfill));
        stream.on('error', reject); // presumably
    });
}
```

With everything wrapped in `new Promise(...)` , `try{} catch() {}` is unnecessary as any synchronous error will result in Promise rejection.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot. : )